# Is distance preserved in sublattices?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, order-theory

Let $L$ be a locally finite (every interval in $L$ is finite) and graded (there exists a rank function $\rho:L\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\rho(x)=\rho(y)+1$ whenever $x$ covers $y$) lattice.

Is it true that for every finite (induced) sublattice $S$ of $L$ ($S$ preserves the meet and join of $L$) the distance between vertices in the (underlying undirected graph of the) Hasse diagram of $S$ is equal to the distance between them in the Hasse diagram of $L$?

A simple proof/counter example would be appreciated.

Edit:
As @William Elliot answered below, a sublattice does not preserve distances, I intended $S$ to be convex...
Let $S$ be some interval $[u,v]$ in $L$ (it can be shown that it is a sublattice as needed).
Is the distance preserved in this case?

Comment: I would think your conjecture is correct.   Being graded implies the lattice is modular;  is the converse true?  For these lattices, doesn't every upward progressing path from a to b have the same length?

Comment: @WilliamElliot I don't know if being graded is enough to imply that the lattice is modular... if it is, the proof of my original question will be easier... can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the lattice 0 < a,b < 1 and the sublattice {0,1}.

Comment: From the brevity of your reply, I suspect you believe this is a counterexample.  A few more words, such as "the distance between [vertices]" is not preserved (with example), would greatly improve it for many Readers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @William_Elliot, I intended $S$ to be convex and edited the question.